# Salesforce website is not locating css selectors but is recognising ONLY Full XPATH

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver, salesforce-lightning

so I am trying automate  salesforce website, and the website is only recognising full xpath. if i use any css selctors (apart from the login page) it is showing no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a[title=Accounts]"}
so yeah please help. I am a beginner in using selenium

wd.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.slds-input[placeholder='Search apps and items...']"));

a lot more in the similar vein but did not help